# C# add Scrollbars to Panel with big BackgroundImage

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm very new in c# and visual studio and i try a little bit to learn. 
my problem is i have created a winform and a panel in it. this panel have a background image with a bigger size as the panel, i want to see the picture in orginal size in the panel with scrollbars in the sites and i want create buttons on this panel but the panel dont create automatic scrollbars. how i can solve this ? i tried it to set the width and height but this dont work.

```
Image myimage = new Bitmap(imgPath);
maleTreePanel.BackgroundImage = myimage;
```

i create the panel and set later the background image

Comment: Assign the panel's AutoScrollMinSize property.  It should be myimage.Size plus the scrollbar widths, use the SystemInformation class.

Answer (score 0):

One method is to set maleTreePanel width and height dynamically like

```
maleTreePanel.Width = myimage.Width;
maleTreePanel.Height = myimage.Height;
```

and put maleTreePanel inside another smaller panel that has `AutoScroll = true`. The smaller panel will effectively act as your viewing area for the larger one.